# Delay assignment for a variables reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a system that simply goes to a server and retrieves some text, to maximize the performance I want to send many requests at once. The code looks like this:

```
var okButton.Text = TextSystem.Get("ok",language);
```

However it's allowed to make the TextSystem calls from wherever in the code and mix it up with other code as well. So it's a bit hard for developers to use the system if they have to preload everything before they use it.

So I wounder if there is possible to

1. Start a new thread when there is a TextSystem call
2. Aggregate all the requests to one big after 10ms
3. Delay the assign of value to okButton until the response is received

I want something like this:

```
var okButton1.Text = TextSystem.Get("ok1",language); // Start thread X and buffer the 
// request
var okButton2.Text = TextSystem.Get("ok2",language); // Add ok2 to the request buffer
FinanceCall(); // Execute this call, oh 10ms has passed since thread X started
// send the request with ok1 and ok2 to remote server.
// The server has respond, change the value for okButton1.Text and okButton2.Text.
var okButton3.Text = TextSystem.Get("ok3",language); // Start thread Y and do the same..
```

This code will be executed in ASP.NET so the thing I care about is that okButton1.Text is set before the page get rendered. I was thinking about if some async/await approach would work, but I would like to have some input on how you could solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need to aggregate the requests, but I would suggest have the developers each add there request that gets put into a queue or list then process them all when you want like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var r1 = new Request {Callback = r => Console.WriteLine(r), Parm1 = "ok1", Parm2 = "language"};
            TextSystem.QueueRequest(r1);

            var r2 = new Request {Callback = r => Console.WriteLine(r), Parm1 = "ok2", Parm2 = "language"};
            TextSystem.QueueRequest(r2);

            var r3 = new Request {Callback = r => Console.WriteLine(r), Parm1 = "ok3", Parm2 = "language"};
            TextSystem.QueueRequest(r3);

            var r4 = new Request {Callback = r => Console.WriteLine(r), Parm1 = "ok4", Parm2 = "language"};
            TextSystem.QueueRequest(r4);

            TextSystem.Flush();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public static class TextSystem
    {
        private static readonly List<Request> requests = new List<Request>();

        static TextSystem()
        {
            requests = new List<Request>();
        }

        public static void QueueRequest(Request request)
        {
            requests.Add(request);
        }

        public async static void Flush()
        {
            List<Tuple<Request, string>> results = await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    var list = new List<Tuple<Request, string>>();

                    //process each request
                    foreach (Request request in requests)
                    {
                        //Get data, process or whatever
                        list.Add(new Tuple<Request, string>(request, request.Parm1));
                    }
                    return list;
                });


            //Callback on same thread as the request was initiated on
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                result.Item1.Callback(result.Item2);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Request
    {
        public Action<string> Callback { get; set; }
        public string Parm1 { get; set; }
        public string Parm2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```